# Python multiprocessing to always utilize x number of cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code that uses python's multiprocessing library to do some heavy computation using 8 cores.

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process
random_numbers_list = [random.random()] * 10000000 

for i in range(0, len(random_numbers_list), 8):
    threads = []
    for j in range(i, i + 8):
        if j > len(random_numbers_list) - 1:
            break
        p = Process(target=do_heavy_computation,
                    args=(random_numbers_list[j], j))
        threads.append(p)

    [t.start() for t in threads]
    [t.join() for t in threads]
```

However, the problem is, while all 8 cores is correctly utilized to do the computation in parallel, it waits for the current 8 cores batch to finish until the next 8 cores batch starts. I would like the code to always utilize 8 cores, so that when any of the cores are done, it uses the next available core out of the total 8 cores. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a job for [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

Answer (score 2):

Let a process pool take care of everything for you.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    for index, value in enumerate(random_numbers_list):
        pool.apply(do_heavy_computation, args=(value, index))
```

The `Pool()` initializer has additional arguments that you can investigate.  But the above code is all you need to run your code on 8 processes, and wait until it's finished.

The most important argument you may need to change is `maxtasksperchild`, whose default value is `None`.  Eight threads will be created and all your tasks will be run on those eight threads.  You can change this to `masktasksperchild=1`, and each thread will run only 1 task, and then die and be replaced by a fresh thread.  That's what you're doing above, but it's unclear if that's necessary.